# Issue with using charindex and substring

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, substring, charindex

I have below code:

```
declare @error varchar(max)
set @error = 'Invalid content. Error ids=[3001]'

select substring(@error, charindex('[', @error)+1, charindex(']', @error)-1)
```

I want to get number: 3001, but current result is

```
3001]
```

Anyone can explain, why still have bracket ']' ?

Answer (score 3):

Because the third parameter of `substring` means `length of substring`, not from index to index

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql

You can try this

```
select substring(@error, charindex('[', @error)+1, charindex(']', @error) - charindex('[', @error) - 1)
```

Comment: your solution still return 3001], because you have in third parameter '-1'.

Comment: Have you tried it @ŁukaszKorol ? My demo:  http://rextester.com/ITYZP64395

Answer (score 2):

This'll more easily be explained by splitting out the query into parts.

Firstly:

```
SELECT charindex('[', @error)+1;
```

This returns 29. Seems correct. Next:

```
SELECT charindex(']', @error) -1;
```

This returns 32. This means you're therefore doing:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(@error, 29, 32);
```

See where you're going wrong now? The 3rd parameter is how many characters you want. You don't want 32, you want 4. Thus, instead try:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(@error, CHARINDEX('[', @error)+1, CHARINDEX(']', @error) - (CHARINDEX('[', @error)+1));
```

Comment: thank you very much for your explanation. It was easy.

Answer (score 1):

The third parameter of [SUBSTRING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql) is length. You are passing `charindex(']', @error)-1` which equals 32. So therefore it will gather 32 characters from the indicated starting position.

What it looks like you are trying to do is determine the length of the string between the brackets. To do this you need to subtract the index of the left bracket from the index of the right bracket. See below example.

```
declare @error varchar(max)
set @error = 'Invalid content. Error ids=[3001]'

select substring(@error, charindex('[', @error)+1, (CHARINDEX(']', @error)-1) - charindex('[', @error))
```